# Rails 5.1 and Cloudinary: Image files is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloudinary, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm working with Heroku in app made in Rails 5.1.1 which uses Cloudinary like image server and [atacchinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary) to upload it.

This is the first time I use attachinary with rails 5, and when I upload the image with the input  `<%= f.attachinary_file_field :image_event %>`, it works fine. The image is uploaded and I can see it on cloudinary dashboard.

The question is: when I going to create the information, it returns to edit the info in the crud with a error in the file input.

> Saying: Image files is invalid

I think its something with association, because the image is uploaded, but I'm not sure. The error occurs in development and in production.

The field is already in required parameters on controller

```
development:
  cloud_name: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  api_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  api_secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  enhance_image_tag: false // changed to false to work with rails 5
  static_image_support: false
production:
  cloud_name: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  api_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  api_secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  enhance_image_tag: false
  static_image_support: false
test:
  cloud_name: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  api_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  api_secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_image_support: true
```

**My Model Event:**

```
  has_attachment  :image_event, accept: [:jpg, :png, :gif]
```

Comment: Can you share your form and controller codes too?

Answer (score 1):

The error is suggesting that the ORM might not be properly set up when an image is included through Attachinary. Make sure to include the specific ORM you wish to use by adding following line to your application.rb file (or custom initializer):

e.g.

```
require "attachinary/orm/YOUR_ORM" # active_record or mongoid
```

More info on that can be found here:
https://github.com/assembler/attachinary#installation